# Angular 7 for loop range, from x to x+y

Tags: angular

I wish to use a for loop in angular because I want to display a limited amount of data in a ngFor loop, with a page system. I mean that I want to display 1 to 20 datas. Then I click on a "next" button to go to the next page, so I should display datas from 21 to 40, etc...

I don't understand how I can do that with the ngFor loop even after I read the documentation (https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wish to use a for loop in angular because I want to display a
>   limited amount of data in a ngFor loop, with a page system. I mean
>   that I want to display 1 to 20 datas. Then I click on a "next" button
>   to go to the next page, so I should display datas from 21 to 40,
>   etc...

### Are you looking for pagination?

> If so **CHECK** **[WORKING STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-paging)**

Your **`component.html`** can look something like this

```
<div class="container">
  <pager [itemCount]="100" [(pageIndex)]="pageIndex" [pageSize]="pageSize"></pager>
  <table class="table table-sm">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let fieldName of fieldNames">{{fieldName}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of items | slice:pageIndex*pageSize:(pageIndex+1)*pageSize">
        <td *ngFor="let name of fieldNames">{{item[name]}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

and your **`component.ts`** might look something like this

```
export class AppComponent  {
  items: object[];
  fieldNames: string[];
  pageIndex: number;
  pageSize: number;

  constructor(appService: AppService) {
    this.items = appService.getOrders(100);
    this.fieldNames = [ 'No', 'Name', 'Date', 'Amount' ];
    this.pageIndex = 0;
    this.pageSize = 10;
  }
}
```

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly!

You can play with two variables which will be used as an offset (Starting point) and limit (Ending point):

HTML Code:

```
<div class="example-container">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Input" [(ngModel)]="limit">
  </mat-form-field>
   <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="generateNumbers()">Generate page list</button>
<div *ngFor="let page of pageList">
  {{page}}
</div>
</div>
```

TS Code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

/** @title Simple form field */
@Component({
  selector: 'form-field-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'form-field-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['form-field-overview-example.css'],
})
export class FormFieldOverviewExample {
  offset: any = 1;
  limit: any = 20;

  pageList: any[] = [];

  generateNumbers() {
    this.pageList = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= this.limit; i++) {
      this.pageList.push(i);
    }
  }
}
```

[`WORKING DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uqvz1r)

Answer (score 1):

You can bind new data to View. The bind data initialized to The 1-20 of source data. When clicked the `next button` change the data to 21-40.